# Update UIView after Locking and Unlocking phone

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uiview

My app is running an `NSURLSession` where it downloads a file. However, when the user locks the phone I cannot update the subviews on the screen. They are frozen. I have a method getting called when the phone locks via the app delegate; however, it will not update any subviews.

I have tried placing the updates on main thread or background and nothing works. I simply want to adjust visibility of certain objects but not longer can do that after screen is locked. I hope that is enough info. Any help would be awesome. Thanks guys!

This is what is getting called via the app delegate when the phone is locked

```
-(void)pauseDownload{


// I want to update the UI!!!!


[session invalidateAndCancel];
bytesSum = 0;
percent = 0;

[HUD hide:YES];
self.downloadButton.hidden = NO;
HUD.progress = percent;
[HUD  setLabelText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Loading %.0f%%",(percent*100)]];


}
```

None of the visibility permissions will work and the objects are un responsive. My guess is that I am losing a pointer to the objects some how when the phone is locked. Can I regain them? Am I way off idk?!

Comment: Updating the views is not something that one would do when the phone is locked. This can easily be done in the method -(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;

Comment: I am trying to update the view once the phone is unlocked after being locked. The elements that were visible when locked should no longer be visible when unlocked. However I cannot seem to update them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this in loadView or viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
  selector:@selector(becomeActive)
    name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
      object:nil];

-(void) becomeActive
{
  NSLog(@"ACTIVE");
  //
}
```

Comment: It is not the problem of being notified but the problem of being able to update the view. The code is called but the objects are un responsive.

Comment: make sure that you have strong and nonatomic reference to the view you want to update

Answer (score 1):

You can update UI in `viewWillAppear:` life cycle view controller method:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    // update UI
}
```

[Also, read apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Once device is lock there is no certain methodology or no way to create the background process or continue download process.

The only possible way can be used is we while during the downloading process if user lock the device & app goes into background downloaded content should be saved. So once when application is again  active the downloading process should start from where it stopped.

Comment: I am not trying to even continue the download just update the view so they can then start the download over.

Comment: update UIView at what time ? when it goes to background or when it becomes active ?